# Python Running an Excel Macro

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to use python to run an excel macro and then close excel. I have the following:

```
 import win32com.client
 import os

 xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
 wb = xl.workbooks.open("X:\Location\Location2\File1.xlsm")
 xl.run("File1.xlsm!WorkingFull")
 xl.Visible = True
 wb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
 xl.Quit
```

My script will Open and close fine if I take out the xl.run("File1.xlsm!WorkingFull")
When I run this I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\File1.py", line 6, in 
    xl.run("File1.xlsm!WorkingFull")
  File "", line 2, in run
  com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u"Cannot run   the   macro 'File1.xlsm!WorkingFull'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.", u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

I have macros enabled and I know its in the workbook, what is the problem?

Comment: have you tried reducing the call? `xl.run("WorkingFull")`?

Comment: Make sure your macro is not private. Also try `xl.run(wb.WorkingFull)` and see if that works.

Comment: worked, but I am getting the error, but it seems to run my macro. The only reason I know this is my macro saves a file off. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\file1.py", line 6, in <module> xl.run("WorkingFull") File "<COMObject Excel.Application>", line 2, in run com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146788248), None)

Answer (score 5):

please see below the code for running an Excel macro using python. You can find this code in this [Site - Link](https://sites.google.com/site/exceldriven/selenium-webdriver/python-scripts/run-an-excel-macro-using-python). Use this site for other references for excel, vba and python scripts which might be helpful in the future.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import unittest
import os.path
import win32com.client

class ExcelMacro(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_excel_macro(self):
        try:
            xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
            xlsPath = os.path.expanduser('C:\test1\test2\test3\test4\MacroFile.xlsm')
            wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
            xlApp.Run('macroName')
            wb.Save()
            xlApp.Quit()
            print("Macro ran successfully!")
        except:
            print("Error found while running the excel macro!")
            xlApp.Quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: cpBurnz - I understand your concern and I have placed the code above which will show the users how to run an excel macro utilizing python. If you could kindly vote on my answer as useful it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That looks much better.